# How to get a widget element in Fragment When use ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I have a `ViewPager` for reading data content. I bookmark item position and scrollY of data in my last used. When I open `MainActivity`, I set `ViewPager` to last position item I used. But I don't know how to setScrollY for `RecyclerView` I scrolled last use. 
How to get `RecyclerView` in `ReadingDataFragment` to `setScrollY` from `MainActivity`?
In `MainActivity`(I extends AppCompatActivity):

```
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_main_activity);

    List<Data> list = new ArrayList<Data>();
    list = ...;

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    CustomDataAdapter adapter = new CustomDataAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), list, getApplicationContext());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    //check bookmark data
    int positionBookmark = getPositionBookmark();
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(positionBookmark);

    //check scroll bookmark
    int scrollYBookmark = getScrollYBookmark();
    //Here, How to get RecyclerView in ReadingDataFragment and set position.
}
...
```

In `CustomDataAdapter` (extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter):

```
...  
  private List<Data> list;
  private Context context;

  public CustomDataAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Data> list, Context context) {
    super(fm);
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return new ReadingDataFragment(context, list.get(position));
  }

  @Override
  public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
  }
  ...
```

In `ReadingDataFragment`(I extends Fragment):

```
...
private Data data;
    private Context context;

    public ReadingDataFragment(Context context, Data data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_item_view_data, container, false);

        RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv_item);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        rv.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        ReadingDataAdapter adapter = ....
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
...
```

Comment: You won't be able to get `recyclerview`'s instance until fragment's `onCreateView` is called. Inside your `fragment`, you might want to first know that it is the current item in the `viewpager` may be using a custom method that you call from main activity when setting `viewpager`'s current item. If found true, then inside the fragment itself you may want to set last scroll position of recyclerview.